# Maximum Testers in TestFlight

Tags: ios, testflight

What is the maximum number of testers that i can add to [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) Account? Is there any limitation? I have created and built iPhone application and uploaded to TestFlight. Then I added a Tester. He could download and install that. Since I am using Free account of Test flight, I would like to know its limitations.

Comment: That's a question you should be asking TestFlight, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE**: T*his answer applies to the old testflightapp.com services. The rules have changes now that Apple owns TestFlight.*

---

You are limited, by Apple, to only having 100 Ad Hoc devices. This is a per year limit. If you add a device, and then remove it, it does not let you add another device.

So, even if TestFlight let you add more than 100 devices, you still could not install the Ad Hoc provisioned app on them.

Comment: so how i make ipa withot creating ad hoc certificate and signing?

Comment: I don't know of a way. Presumably jailbroken iPhones can do that. But a better question is, why? Why do you need more than 100 testers? http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20000319.html is an interesting, and short, read. Bottom line, it is better to test more frequently with fewer users than rarely with many users.

Answer (score 2):

As of 13.11.2015, there was an update from Apple:

> To make your TestFlight experience even better, we’ve made some
>   significant changes. You can now invite up to 2000 external testers
>   and up to 25 internal testers per app. You can also test up to 100
>   apps at the same time for up to 60 days, and submit up to 6 updates
>   per day to your external testers.

Comment: I was asking about the old test flight platform. See the accepted answer. But at the moment your answer is the right one  Time matters

Answer (score 1):

I believe the limitation depends on the iOS program your are enrolled in.

The limit of 100 devices is for the iOS Developer program.

There is no limit if you are enrolled in the iOS Developer Enterprise program and are distributing your Enterprise signed app.

See "Team member Limit" in [TestFlight FAQ](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402851-testflight-faq)

Answer (score 1):

Inviting TestFlight Beta Testers

Internal Testers

Get feedback quickly by sharing your beta builds with up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Technical or Admin role in iTunes Connect. Each member can test on up to 10 devices.

External Testers

Once you’re ready, you can invite up to 1,000 users who are not part of your development organization to beta test an app that you intend for public release on the App Store. Apps made available to external testers require a Beta App Review and must comply with the full App Store Review Guidelines before testing can begin. A review is required for new versions of your app that contain significant changes. Up to 10 apps can be tested at a time, internally or externally.

Comment: Can you provide a source for where you got this?