# Distribute iOS app to more than 1000 people for beta testing

Tags: ios, ios8, testflight

I want to distribute my application to more than 1000 testers before it makes way to the App Store Which is the preferred way for doing the same?

One method I know is to test via Test Flight but it has limit of 1000, Is there any other way around ?

Comment: Check this - http://www.diawi.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can enroll for [Enterprises program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) and distribute for more than 1000 devices using enterprise Adhoc certificate.TestFlight allow maximum 1000 users only.

Answer (score 1):

The only other way around is to use enterprise certificates:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: But they are saying that "Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees.", Can I distribute to those who are not employees?

Comment: @Abhishek Officially, no, and there is no other way around (except perhaps having multiple developer accounts or jailbroken devices).

Comment: There is a kind of an App Store outside the App Store called Emu4iOSStore. I only used it for one app but I would investigate it since it allows you to actually download an app outside(!) the App Store. It seems absolutely legit since before installing, you get a message that this app is from an 'untrusted/unknown' (something like that) developer. So it seems Apple knows and approved this(?). Anyway, I'd check this out.

Comment: @bauerMusic I think such kind of solution tends to get broken by apple updates...

Comment: @Antzi After some digging, it seems it is a kind of an 'Emulator'. And yea, it is not safe as far as Apple blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

Distribute it by uploading application's ipa on TestFlight website

Comment: It has limit of 1000 users

Comment: this link may help you [maximum testers in TestFlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312010/maximum-testers-in-testflight)